# Kate text editor cannot handle lines longer than 1024?

Tags: linux, text-editor, kate

This is a very annoying limitation for editing some config files, such as mozilla `prefs.js`. It usually contains lines longer than that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a well know "security option", it is configurable:

Go to:

```
Settings / configure editor / open and save
set line length limit [ 1024 ]
```

and change 1024

[image]

Comment: Setting the Line Length Limit to '0' will disable it completely.

Answer (score 1):

If you are against VIM and EMACS (give them a try), there's gnome's alternative Gedit, then theres also the lightweight IDE Geany, and Mousepad, and there are the full fledged IDEs like Ajunta, NetBeans, QTCreator, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is nowadays fixed, see https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=345775

In Kate 19.12.3 from 2019 line with thousands of columns seems to work fine. Though 127 000 column causes lag unlike in for example Geany.