# Fix Kate text editor line limit via bash script

Tags: bash, shell, editor, kate

The Kate text editor has a default line length of 1024 chars. I need to change this. And I need to change it via a **bash script** (it's for automated installs).

Here's some background: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13496876/463994

I would appreciate a bash script that changes that sets the default line length to 0 chars.

Comment: I don't use KDE, but according to [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/168413) on AskUbuntu there should be a config file `/home/$USER/.kde/share/config/katerc`. I'd check that file for the line-length setting. Once you identified the setting, you can probably modify it via `sed`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - yes indeed, that file contains `Line Length Limit=<somevalue>` which is what I need to change. Thanks!

Comment: If you can give me the `sed` line that will change `Line Length Limit=<somevalue>` to `Line Length Limit=0` I'll accept your answer. Even better, how would I use sed to comment out the original value and insert the new line right below it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With permission of **Ansgar Wiechers**, I post a [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) solution that seems to work for me:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/^Line Length Limit=.*$/##&\nLine Length Limit=0/' ~/.kde4/share/config/katerc
```

It comments current value adding `##` at the beginning of the line and appending after that the same with `0` as value. I use the `-i` switch that appends a `.bak` suffix as backup to the original file. Use `sed -i -e ...` (note the space between both switches) to modify the file in place. Be careful with this last option.

---

In my case, I prefer to modify files in-place with [vim](/questions/tagged/vim), so as extra I will post a one-liner that does the same than the previous [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command, only that its backup file is suffixed with `~`:

```
vim \
    +'/^\v\cline\s+length\s+limit' \
    -u NONE \
    -N \
    -c 'set backup | yank | s/\v^/##/ | put | s/\v(\=\s*)\d+/\10/ | x' \
~/.kde4/share/config/katerc
```

Comment: Thank you! That's excellent. It works and I learned something useful about `sed`. (I'll stick with the sed solution for now.)

Answer (score 6):

If KDE is installed, use `kwriteconfig`. This is a KDE tool to modify config files:

```
kwriteconfig --file katerc --group "Kate Document Defaults" --key "Line Length Limit" 0
```

The value `0` entirely disables the line length limit. In this case, the edited file is `katerc`, located in `~/.kde4/share/config/`. Of course, you can choose any other file here, such as `kilerc`.